# React TypeScript type for mousedown and touchstart events"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I specify a TypeScript type for `mousedown` and `touchstart` events?

```
function useOnClickOutside(ref: React.RefObject<any>, handler: () => void) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (event: React.TouchEvent | React.MouseEvent) => {
      if (!ref || !ref.current) {
        return;
      }
      const elem = document.getElementsByClassName(uniqueClassName)[0];
      if (elem.contains(event.target)) {
        return;
      }
      handler();
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", listener);
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", listener);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", listener);
      document.removeEventListener("touchstart", listener);
    };
  }, [ref, handler]);
}
```

Comment: I think you should use: `(event:MouseEvent|TouchEvent) =>` you are not using React to add the event listener.

Answer (score 7):

You are using DOM native events, **NOT** React [SyntheticEvent](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

So the type should be DOM [MouseEvent](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.mouseevent.html) and [TouchEvent](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.touchevent.html) interfaces.

E.g.

```
function useOnClickOutside(ref: React.RefObject<any>, handler: () => void) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (event: TouchEvent | MouseEvent) => {
      if (!ref || !ref.current) {
        return;
      }
      const uniqueClassName = 'test';
      const elem = document.getElementsByClassName(uniqueClassName)[0];
      if (elem.contains(event.target as Node)) {
        return;
      }
      handler();
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', listener);
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', listener);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', listener);
      document.removeEventListener('touchstart', listener);
    };
  }, [ref, handler]);
}
```

TypeScript version: `"typescript": "^4.1.2"`